# Add/Remove markers from Google maps by toggling a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am building a mobile web app with a mapping (Google Maps) component.
I am trying to create a toggle `onclick="gas()"` that will add (then remove) markers to the map based on a keyword (gas), so that when someone is driving around and looking for a gas station they can click the gas icon and it adds gas stations to the map.
Everything works properly EXCEPT the removing part.  I cannot get the second part of the toggle to work properly, ie removing the markers from the map.  I believe I am missing something simple here but cannot figure it out (I think it is the `else` portion, specifically the `clearMarkers()` function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, I am a beginner JS programmer with no training at all and used a mash up of code from the web.
Here is the code.

Javascript:

```
//Gas
var gas_markers = null;
function gas() {
if (gas_markers == null) {
    document.getElementById('gas').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(175,175,175)";
    document.getElementById('gas').style.borderColor = "black";
    document.getElementById('gas').style.color = "rgb(75,75,75)";

    var request = {
        location: arena,
        radius: 3500,
        keyword: ["gas"]
  };
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var gas_markers = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: place.geometry.location,
    draggable: false,
    raiseOnDrag: false,
    map: map,
    icon: "images/gas1.png",
    labelContent: "",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 0),
    labelClass: "pin", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.95}
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  google.maps.event.addListener(gas_markers, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('Promo Code:<br>Gas');
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
 gas_markers = 'one';

 } 
else

{       
    function clearMarkers() {
        callback(null);
        gas_markers = [];

                        } 

    document.getElementById('gas').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(75,75,75)";
    document.getElementById('gas').style.borderColor = "gray";
    document.getElementById('gas').style.color = "rgb(175,175,175)";  

    gas_markers = null;
    }       

} 
 //Gas - end
```

HTML:

`<div onclick="gas()" id="gas"><div class="label-map">Gas</div></div>`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: how are you populating the gas_markers array?  There is no map in your posted code.

Comment: This code is from a .js file, the Map portion (and div tag code) is part of the HTML file.  Do you want me to upload that too?

Comment: This is the sample from google's code library....i guess it doesn't put the locations in an array.  Do they still need to be in an array to all be removeded from the map?

Comment: You need to be able to access them to remove them (Google's example doesn't do that).  Doesn't _have_ to be an array, but that is the most common way to do it and the simplest if you don't have set/fixed markers.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.  Is that an easy fix to my code above or would it need to be rewritten from scratch...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a global array to hold the markers (gas_markers)
2. modify your clearMarkers function to process through that array, removing the markers from the map before deleting it:

   function clearMarkers() {

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < gas_markers.length; i++) {
       gas_markers[i].setMap(null);
   }
   gas_markers = [];
   ```

   }

working code snippet:

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

//Gas
var gas_markers = null;

function gas() {
    if (gas_markers === null) {
        document.getElementById('gas').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(175,175,175)";
        document.getElementById('gas').style.borderColor = "black";
        document.getElementById('gas').style.color = "rgb(75,75,75)";

        var request = {
            location: map.getCenter(),
            radius: 3500,
            keyword: ["gas"]
        };
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                if (gas_markers === null) gas_markers = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var gas_marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: place.geometry.location,
                draggable: false,
                raiseOnDrag: false,
                map: map,
                // icon: "images/gas1.png",
                labelContent: "",
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 0),
                labelClass: "pin", // the CSS class for the label
                labelStyle: {
                    opacity: 0.95
                }
            });
            gas_markers.push(gas_marker);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            google.maps.event.addListener(gas_marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent('Promo Code: <br> Gas');
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
        // gas_markers = 'one';

    } else {

        clearMarkers();
        document.getElementById('gas').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(75,75,75)";
        document.getElementById('gas').style.borderColor = "gray";
        document.getElementById('gas').style.color = "rgb(175,175,175)";

        gas_markers = null;

    }

    function clearMarkers() {

        for (var i = 0; i < gas_markers.length; i++) {
            gas_markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        gas_markers = [];
    }

}
//Gas - end
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div onclick="gas()" id="gas">
    <div class="label-map">Gas</div>
</div>
```